# Python-Reportlab error: ValueError: format not resolved

Tags: python, exception, reportlab

when I was using python-reportlab to create a pdf document, sometimes it throws out an exception: `ValueError: format not resolved talk.google.com`, I wonder why this came out, and how to solve it, the full error stack is like below:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweets2pdf/tweets2pdf.py", line 42,
in generate_thread
tpdoc.dump()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweets2pdf/pdfgen.py", line 609, in
dump
self.pdfdoc.build(self.elements, onFirstPage = self.on_first_page,
onLaterPages = self.on_later_pages)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-
packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 1117, in build
BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-
packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 906, in build
self._endBuild()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-
packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py", line 848, in _endBuild
if getattr(self,'_doSave',1): self.canv.save()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfgen/canvas.py", line
1123, in save
self._doc.SaveToFile(self._filename, self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 235, in SaveToFile
f.write(self.GetPDFData(canvas))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 257, in GetPDFData
return self.format()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 417, in format
IOf = IO.format(self)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 869, in format
fcontent = format(self.content, document, toplevel=1) # yes this is at
top level
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 102, in format
f = element.format(document)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 1635, in format
return D.format(document)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 667, in format
L = [(format(PDFName(k),document)+" "+format(dict[k],document)) for k in
keys]
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 102, in format
f = element.format(document)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfdoc.py",
line 1764, in format
if f is None: raise ValueError, "format not resolved %s" % self.name
ValueError: format not resolved talk.google.com
```

Comment: What data did you pass to reportlab library?

Comment: I've solved this problem, when I gave an link without the protocol prefix to the element, such as <a href="stackoverflow.com">s</a>, it throw out this exception, but when I added "http://" to the link url, it works.

Comment: Anyone who finds this on google later may wan to know that you'll also see this terribly worded error if you attempt to link a local anchor tag (href="#blah") to an anchor that doesn't exist in the document.